# Bundling files for node.js through browserify does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, browserify

I am using **browserify v13.0.0**

I have an `a.js` which just has a `module.exports = {a: 1}`

And I run browserify as so:
`browserify --node --debug a.js > bundle.js`

In the **node REPL**,

```
> require ('./bundle.js')
{}
>
```

Why the `{}` ? Shouldn't it give me `{a: 1}`?

Although I've reduced my problem to the simplest case, this behavior is stopping me from bundling a project involving multiple coffeescript files into a single file for node & browsers.

Ive also tried `--bare`, `--no-builtins`, `--no-bf`

The same thing works with the **standalone** option. So if I do
`browserify --node --standalone abc --debug a.js > bundle.js`

```
> require ('./bundle.js')
{a: 1}
>
```

Standalone can be `abc` or anything else! It just works

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same thing, and it seems to be connected to the way the UMD header is generated. The standalone parameter sets a property of that name on the root object (which seems to be module.exports when loading the module in node) but i'm not sure yet. I'll have a look at the browserify source for generating the UMD header, and then i'll know more. For now, i'd say stick with the 'standalone' option